# Could not find file or assembly when generating specflow tests

Tags: specflow

I've been happily developing SpecFlow tests on this machine for a while now. Today when I changed some tests and tried to regenerate them I keep getting

`Custom tool error: Could not load file or assembly 'TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=1.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41' or one of its dependencies.`

I have SpecFlow 1.8.1 installed on my computer and am pulling in the SpecFlow package from NuGet. I've tried reinstalling both of these components with no luck.

Any suggestions as to why this might be happening or where I should go to find more information would be much appreciated.

Comment: Whats the location of the specflow installation? Is it the default program files directory?. If it was downloaded as a zip maybe the dll needs to be unblocked, right click the dll and select properties and then unblock. I would say check your project references but this looks likes its an error from running the Generator

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference to the SpecFlow dll into your project AND set its "Copy Local" property to TRUE. Then it should work.

However, if you are trying to run the ms test from TFS, then you may still get this error. (I'm still trying to find out how to fix that.) But at least the above should fix your immediate problem.